# Cant SSH over IPSEC

Tags: ssh, ipsec, amazon-vpc

I am in AWS and i have two VPCS between virgina and oregon and I am trying to SSH from either region.

My rules allow everything needed  and I can ping

```
Virgina
   IPSEC-Machine   10.10.1.47
   Host-Machine-V  10.10.4.125

Oregon
   IPSEC-Machine   10.20.0.97
   Host-Machine-O  10.20.1.190
```

I can ping between regions

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-20-0-97 ~]$ ping 10.10.1.47
PING 10.10.1.47 (10.10.1.47) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.1.47: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=60.5 ms
--- 10.10.1.47 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 1 received, 50% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 60.560/60.560/60.560/0.000 ms
```

SSH seems to work

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-1-47 ~]$ nc -v -w 1 10.20.1.190 -z 22
Connection to 10.20.1.190 22 port [tcp/ssh] succeeded!
[ec2-user@ip-10-10-1-47 ~]$
```

But when on `10.10.1.47` and I type `ssh 10.20.1.190` it just hangs and I get nothing. The keys are all correct but even if I get a permission denied at this point I would be happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what could be causing this, but here are a few things to try:

Use the EC2 hostname to connect - it's possible that something in the addressing is causing problems between the regions. My only guess at the moment is that the IP address is actually someone else's server in the Virginia region, and not your server in Oregon.

Run the nmap portscanner to ensure that the port is open. I saw that you used netcat, but a proper portscan may help.

Run ssh -vvv to get verbose output, this may give you some information to figure out what the problem is.